# Free software to draw route on map based on coordinates

Tags: maps, drawing, geo-location

I want to develop html based geolocation tracker. Now I am looking for a software which can draws route based on coordinates. Any one know free software to do the task?

Edit:
I can almost do it with below website:
http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/draw/

But I want the track to be able to draw each node and each node should have time information.

Comment: You can't beat [Leaflet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaflet_(software))